# tshark task started in background doesn't generates any file

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to start tshark task in the background to collect some data to a file. My code is below:

```
command = '"tshark -i 5 -Y "udp" -T fields -E seperator=, -E header=y -e frame.time_relative -e ip.id -F k12text > me.txt"'
command1 = shlex.split(command)
tsharkProc = subprocess.Popen(command1,
                              close_fds=True,
                              executable="C:\\Program Files\\Wireshark\\tshark.exe")
time.sleep(60)
print("done")
```

Seems that the code is running, but the me.txt is not generated.

The code located in `c:\temp\Temp` and the output of `pwd` is `c:\\temp\\Temp`

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Redirections such as `> me.txt` are not handled by the program itself, but by the shell.  No shell is involved here, so that part of the command line is interpreted as simply two more arguments to `tshark` - I have no idea what it's going to do with them.  You could run the command with `shell=True` so that there's something to handle the redirection, or you could remove the redirection from the command and instead read from the `Popen` object and write to a file in your Python code.

Comment: I need that the data will be written to a file. On the main process, I'm going to read the data and parse it. The fields mentioned here are just for testing. The program shall run for few hours - so the writing to the file with tshark shall all the time the program is running.

Comment: Also, I'll have to analyze data from different protocols, so I'll need couple of such processes